# Can't connect to Synology DiskStation through HTTPS when using Windows 7 Import

Tags: windows-7, ssl-certificate, synology

a little background to my problem:

I have a Synology DiskStation 213j that I use as a backup/data storage solution. When I'm at work, I would like to push and pull files from my DiskStation but I can't use VPN which is forbidden for outgoing connections. So I wanted to try to use HTTPS so I can at least connect securely to the web interface. I mostly use Chrome which uses the Windows Certificate Store. So I tried importing a self-signed certificate into it, without success. I still get a warning in Chrome telling me the connection is not secure because it can't be verified. When I import the certificate into Firefox though, it works and I can connect through HTTPS.

I checked my domain on this site: http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

It shows no errors, only a warning that the certificate is self-signed. Which is OK in this case.

Any got any idea why importing the certificate into Windows 7 doesn't work? I tried `Right-Click domain.mydomain.de.crt File --> Install certificate --> Next --> both options here (in case of "Place certificate in following store:" I selected "Third Party Root Certificate Authorities")` to no avail.

Comment: I also followed http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754841.aspx without success.

Comment: Weird, I added the URL (with the port) to the certificate's cross-certificate properties tab. Now, I can connect with Internet Explorer also but still not with Chrome. Hmmm...